# Braces - At start and end

Tags: terminology, braces

I know that "{ }" are braces. But I don't know and can't seem to find what "{" or "}" alone are. If I need to differentiate them, what should I call the first and what the second ("opening" and "ending", "left" and "right"?) Thanks a lot

Comment: I think **opening** and **closing** braces goes best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unicode standard has these [definitions](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=bracket):

> { -- Left Curly Bracket, formerly called Opening Curly Bracket
>
> } -- Right Curly Bracket, formerly called Closing Curly Bracket

Curly brackets ( { } ) are different from square brackets ( [ ] ).

Unicode also [defines](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=bracket) many other kinds of brackets.

Comment: ...and in AmE, what BrE calls *curly brackets* are more often called [*braces*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket). So: *left brace* and *right brace*. (And apparently in InE they are called *flower brackets*.)

Comment: @Drew: I too am accustomed to calling curly brackets _braces_.

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer, I can assert that these are typically called opening and closing curly braces, at least in my line of work. I don't know whether there's an official name for them, but that's what we call them.

Opening, of course, being `{` and closing, `}`. I imagine you know that, but just in the interest of being complete.

The same naming applies to open and close (we often abbreviate the `-ing` off because we're lazy) parentheses, square brackets, and whatever other type of bracket you may find.